# python - stop waiting for input() when a condition (not timer) is met

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am a novice programming that really enjoys programming with python.  I am currently working on a program that uses python to set up sockets to establish a tcp connection between two hosts.

My goal is to create a program that could serve an incoming connection and also initiate the establishment of a connection.  In other words once the program is started it would go through the regular socket setup for a server and start listening for an incoming connection.  While the program is listening for an incoming connection, it would also offer the user the option of initiating a connection by inputting an IP address in the console.

The goal is... if the user never input an IP address the program would simply continue to listen for an incoming connection.  **If an incoming connection was made the program would exit out of the user input and notify the user an incoming connection was made, then disallow the option of establishing an outgoing connection via console input.** (I know both could be handled with threading, but I want the program to only handle one connection, whether that be as server or client).

However, if the user typed an IP address the program would attempt to establish a connection to the inputted IP.  If a connection was established it would stop listening for an incoming connection and focus on the outgoing connection.

I highlighted my problem above.  I need a way of exiting out of the input() prompt when a condition is met (when an incoming connection is established).  Currently, when a connection is made, I print "Incoming Connection Established!" however, after this is printed the terminal still waits for the user to input...

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

ipForInitiating = ''

host = ''
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(2)

def checkForIncoming():
    while ipForInitiating == '':
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('################################\nIncoming Connection 
               Established!\n Address = '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))
        break #Once connection is established break checkForOutgoing() and 
              #CheckForIncoming().  However, continue handleing incoming 
              #connection...

def checkForOutgoing():
    while True:
        if ipForInitiating != '':
            try:
                s.connect((ipForInitiating,port))
            except socket.error as e:
                print(str(e))

            break #Once connection is established break checkForIncoming() 
                  #and CheckForOutgoin.  However, continue handleing 
                  #outgoing connection...

print("Waiting for a connection...")

start_new_thread(checkForIncoming,())
start_new_thread(checkForOutgoing,())

ipForInitiating = input("...Or enter an ip address to initiate the 
connection.\n")

print(ipForInitiating)
```

Comment: That's a very nice description. What have you tried so far and where did you encounter problems?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People can only give you relevant suggestions, if they see your program structure.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am a novice programmer.  I am a little nervous to post my code because I am sure I have inefficiencies.  I find I learn best by diving into a problem and then learning my way through the issues that arise.  This means that I sometimes use modules that I do not fully understand.  One of which is threading.  I threaded a function that continually checks for an incoming connection.

Comment: I will attach the relevant code...

Comment: People on the site won't judge you or the code. They will simply point out things that aren't right about the code. So, next time you will write code you will be aware of the previous flaws and you won't repeat them. P.S.: the code is still missing (don't "attach" it, just add it as a snippet in your question).

Comment: If you are a novice programmer it is probably best not to tackle multithreading without more experience.  It can be difficult even for experienced programmers.  Consider if multithreading is a good idea, many successful sockets programs use multiple processes instead.

Comment: I need to mention, when attempting to start an outgoing connection by typing an ip in, I get a fatal python error.

Answer (score 0):

On a sane operating system, which allows also non-socket descriptors in a [select.select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) call, we can check the readable descriptors returned therefrom to decide whether to accept an incoming or to make an outgoing connection.

```
import select
import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(0)

print("Waiting for a connection...")
print("...Or enter an IP address to initiate the connection.")

if s in select.select([s, sys.stdin], [], [])[0]:   # only interest in readable
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('################################\nIncoming Connection Established!\n'
          'Address = '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))
else:
    ipForInitiating = input()
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    conn.connect((ipForInitiating, port))
    print(ipForInitiating)
```