# Python threaded Socket/OS/Win Error - Unhandled exception in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a python program that once started it will actively listen for incoming connections (via socket) but also offer the user the chance to initiate an outgoing connection.  This is a basic description of my goal program, I go into slightly more detail here...
[python - stop waiting for input() when a condition (not timer) is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847953/python-stop-waiting-for-input-when-a-condition-not-timer-is-met)

I still have not found a solution to the question I raised in the link above. However, I have switched directions slightly and have been working on the functionality aspect of this project.  I have been making progress and I have a working solution for the program receiving a request for connection and sending a request for connection.

When sending a request for connection, the program will connect successfully, but an error will be thrown...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function outgoing at 0x00E4D4B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH\program.py", line 27, in outgoing
    sc.connect((ip, port))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Even though this error is thrown, I still connected successfully to the server/host.

This program is far from done and I know there are still many improvements to be made, but right now I am just trying to get a working/error-free solution.

```
import socket
from _thread import *

ip = ''
host = ''
port = 5555

ss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    ss.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

ss.listen(2)

def incoming():
        conn, addr = ss.accept()
        if conn:
            print('################################\nIncoming Connection Established!\n Address = '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

def outgoing():
    while True:
        if ip != '':
            try:
                sc.connect((ip, port))
                break
            except error as e:
                print(str(e))
                break

print("Waiting for a connection...")

start_new_thread(incoming,())
start_new_thread(outgoing,())

ip = input('...Or enter an ip address to initiate the connection.\n')

outgoing()
```

Comment: Use `threading` instead of `_thread` so that you can `join()` the threads and wait for them to complete before the program terminates (and remove the call to `outgoing()` from your main execution, as the thread already handles that). Otherwise it works fine, I have not been able to reproduce the error you've stated.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar